# WooCommerce - Deselect Default Payment Method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get WooCommerce to not automatically select the first payment method on the checkout page.

This would force the customer to select a payment method on their own and neaten up the checkout page. At present, with the first payment method automatically selected lots of payment information relating to that method is shown to the customer and pushes the other payment methods down the page. On mobile this is a problem as some think this is the only method of payment due to stacking.

The below JS works in removing a default payment method being selected.

However, when I try to then select a payment method, it initially loads the gateway information but then disappears and the selection is removed. I suspect AJAX is causing an issue here due to how this section reloads. This makes it impossible to select a payment method.

Could anyone help expand on this code to allow a gateway selection ? Many Thanks

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $( document ).on( 'updated_checkout', function() {
        var $paymentCheckboxes = $( ".woocommerce-checkout-payment" ).find( '[name="payment_method"]');
        $paymentCheckboxes.attr('checked', false);
        $('.payment_box').hide();
    });
});
```

[image: Payment methods are all unselected, allowing a customer to see which methods are available better.]

Comment: Hey @Alex: Do you have a URL to look at?  Many times, a full picture of all scripts running can be very helpful.

Comment: @ChrisHeney  [link](https://www.banksecom.co.uk/shop/man/arezzo/) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please test with the below code. You need to use the 'updated_checkout' event to reset the payment gateway form after the "?wc-ajax=update_order_review" ajax call.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function deselectDefaultGateway() {
        $('input[name="payment_method"]').each(function (index, item) {
            $(item).attr('checked', false);
        })
        $('.payment_box').hide();
    }

    $(document.body).on('updated_checkout', deselectDefaultGateway);

    $(document).on('click', '.wc_payment_method', function(e){
        if (e.originalEvent !== undefined) {
            $(document.body).off('updated_checkout', deselectDefaultGateway);
        }
    });
});
```

And, for your information, to prevent default selection on loading you can use code like below.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_template_part', 'custom_before_template_part', 10, 4 );
function custom_before_template_part($template_name, $template_path, $located, $args) {
    if ( 'checkout/payment-method.php' == $template_name ) {
        $gateway = $args['gateway'];
        $gateway->chosen = false;
    }
}
```

Woocommerce selects the first payment gateway as the default, but with the above 2 code blocks, you can completely change the behavior. Hope this would help you.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response. I have just tested this with both snippets added. I can confirm no payment method is selected, however, when I then select a method it appears to "load" but does not actually select the method.

Comment: I had tested the code before I post the answer and it was working well. I have just retested and confirmed the code is working correctly on my side. Please check your other code, and if the problem persists, directly contact me so that I can help you to solve the problem. Thank you

Comment: I have just provided a link if it helps to debug. I have got both of your snippets running. [link](https://www.banksecom.co.uk/shop/man/arezzo/)

Comment: Hi Alex, It seems like it is related to the script running order between custom code and woocommerce js code. Please add me on skype rsm0128@hotmail.com, so that I can debug the issue together with you.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this code to select default method.
   
 add_action( 'template_redirect', 'define_default_payment_gateway' );
        function define_default_payment_gateway(){
            if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
                // HERE define the default payment gateway ID
                $default_payment_id = 'stripe';
        
                WC()->session->set( 'chosen_payment_method', $default_payment_id );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello, sorry please read the question in full. WooCommerce already selects a gateway by default, the idea was to remove this so a customer had to select one themselves without the first one being automatically selected.